# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre <T> y <?> en Java?

Tags: java

Entiendo más o menos la genericidad, pero no entiendo cual es la diferencia exacta de esos dos tipos, es decir, si yo hago `<T extends Number>`, el
tipo genérico solo podría ser instancia de cualquier subclase de la clase
límite, o una instancia de la propia clase límite Number, pero si hago `<? extends Number>` ¿se supone que también no? ¿En qué usos difieren cada uno de ellos? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Las wildcards no se pueden usar como parámetro de clase, solo en métodos

El siguiente ejemplo no compila:

```
public class Container <? extends Number> {  } // No compila!
```

Porque no tiene mucho sentido usar una wildcard para definir un tipo que no vas a poder controlar más tarde.

Esto se conoce como varianza en lugar de uso (use-site variance en inglés) y al contrario que en C#, implica que solo puedes usarlas en aquellos sitios donde *vayas* a trabajar con el tipo en cuestión, como en el parámetro de un método o al instanciar una variable.

### Se les pueden dar diferentes restricciones

Las wildcards (`?`) pueden tener restricciones de tipo tanto por arriba como por debajo, pero solo un tipo de cada:

```
por arriba      ? extends Number      // cualquier tipo que sea hijo de Number
por debajo      ? super   Number      // cualquier tipo que sea padre de Number
```

Los tipos parametrizados solo pueden aplicar rerstricción por arriba (sólo `extends`), pero pueden aplicarlo sobre varios tipos:

```
T extends Number & Comparable & Numerable      // cualquier tipo que extienda de Number,
                                               // y que implemente Comparable y Numerable
```

*La clase de la que se extiende se pone primero*

En **Effective java** se puede leer que no es buena idea poner wildcards como tipo de retorno, porque se contagiarían al código cliente y al final todo el mundo tendría que usarlas.

### ¿Dónde se usa cada uno?

> Esto tiene que ver con el principio Producer Extends, Consumer Super (o PECS), definido por Joshua Bloch en **Effective Java** por si lo quieres buscar más en detalle.

De forma general, cuando creas un objeto que es un contenedor, intentas ser muy flexible con el tipo de parámetro que aceptas, y muy estricto con el tipo que devuelves.

Lo que se intenta entonces, en combinación con el ejemplo que te he puesto arriba, es usar una combinación de tipos parametrizados y wildcards para ser lo más flexible posible manteniendo un tipado estático. Te dejo una clase de ejemplo para que lo veas más claro:

```
public class NumberContainer<E extends Number & Comparable> {

    private E item = null;

    public E get() {
        return item;
    }

    public boolean addIfEmpty(E item) {
        if (this.item != null) return false;
        else {
            this.item = item;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean addFromContainer(NumberContainer<? extends E> container) { // si le quitas el extends no compila
        return addIfEmpty(container.item);
    }

    public boolean applyPredicate(Predicate<? super E> predicate) { // lo mismo con este super
        return predicate.test(this.item);
    }

}
```

*Notese que la he restringido a `Number` para que veas que se puede, pero puede ser totalmente genérica.*

Acuérdate también de que el uso de genéricos debería ser transparente para cualquiera que sea cliente del código que tú escribas, por lo que en temas de retorno no deberías devolver nunca una wildcard:

```
// Bien
public NumberContainer<E> mapReturningWildcard(Function<? super E, ? extends E> mapper) {
    return new NumberContainer<E>(mapper.apply(this.item));
}

// Mal
public NumberContainer<? extends E> mapReturningWildcard(Function<? super E, ? extends E> mapper) {
    return new NumberContainer<E>(mapper.apply(this.item));
}
```

*Esto también aparece en el libro ya mencionado*